# Joining multiple tables does not produce the expected number of results

Tags: sql, sqlite

I started working with SQL quite recently and I'm working on a project where I need to join and query several tables to return a list of transactions.

The data is sourced from the [2018 AMS data](https://public.enigma.com/browse/collection/u-s-automated-manifest-system/f3d29ca5-b0de-46f4-910f-54eccece4ad2) (~13GB)

There are 7 tables total, of which I am using 6. Each table contains roughly 11M-17M rows, with a varying amount of columns. Of the tables I am using, each has a segment of the full transaction record that I would need. However, the queries I've attempted thus far only return a portion of the expected number of results.

Below is a summary of the source tables and a crude demonstration of the data they contain:

- [BOL, CARGO, and TARIFF Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mp4C1.png)
- [SHIPPER, CONSIGNEE, NOTIFY Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLXHB.png)

While duplicate identifiers may exist in the SHIPPER, CONSIGNEE, and NOTIFY tables, they can be disregarded as the information is the same.

To get an idea of how many results I should expect, I've run the following query, modified for each table

```
SELECT * FROM NOTIFY
WHERE notify_party_name LIKE '%Company A%'
GROUP BY identifier
```

Which gave me the following counts:

```
SHIPPER:     59 results
CONSIGNEE:  267 results
NOTIFY:     116 results
```

But when I run the query below, it only returns 126 results

```
SELECT 
bol.actual_arrival_date,
tariff.identifier AS Identifier,
tariff.description_sequence_number AS Sequence,
tariff.harmonized_number,
cargo.piece_count,
cargo.description_text,
tariff.harmonized_value,
bol.foreign_port_of_lading AS Origin,
bol.port_of_unlading AS Arrival,
bol.port_of_destination AS Destination,
shipper.shipper_party_name,
consignee.consignee_name,
notify.notify_party_name
FROM tariff
INNER JOIN cargo ON tariff.identifier = cargo.identifier AND tariff.container_number = cargo.container_number
INNER JOIN bol ON tariff.identifier = bol.identifier
INNER JOIN SHIPPER ON tariff.identifier = shipper.identifier
INNER JOIN CONSIGNEE ON tariff.identifier = CONSIGNEE.identifier
INNER JOIN notify ON tariff.identifier = notify.identifier
WHERE shipper.shipper_party_name LIKE '%Company A%' OR consignee.consignee_name LIKE '%Company A%' OR notify.notify_party_name LIKE '%Company A%'
```

Ideally, I'm aiming for the query to return something similar to [my desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMQ4G.png)

I would appreciate any help in identifying what I can do to get the desired result. Thank you.

Comment: Inner joins only return a result when there is data on both sides of the join. Look up outer joins and try using them instead.

Comment: sqlite does not support outer joins and the workaround using unions is far beyond what I am capable of so far

Comment: @Skeven . . . SQLite supports `LEFT JOIN`, which is what you need.